# How to get values from each div using .js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to store data from form created dynamiclly at runtime.

**Please take under consideration that I'm hardcore noob at .js**

I got the idea to append HTML with class like this:

```
<div class="formElement"> some code here </div>
```

... each time user clicks a buton.

It's all great, but I'm stuck on getting values using angular/jquery from each
of those divs and then parsing them into json format that would match viewmodel class. Can you help me with getting all of them?

The types in each div are:

- select list
- number input
- text input

html code

```
<div ng-app="formExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-controller="addRow" ng-click="addLine()">Dodaj przycisk</button>

    <form novalidate class="simple-form">
        <div class="here">
            <div class="formElement">
                Klasa:<select class="optns" ng-model="user.class">
                    <option selected value="1"> Rodzaj... </option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    @*tutaj beda dodane opcje*@
                </select>
                Ilość: <input type="number" ng-model="user.number" value=""/><br />
                Uwagi: <input type="text" ng-model="user.text" value=""/><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
        <input type="submit" ng-controller="addRow" ng-click="getValues()" value="Save" />
    </form>
    <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
    <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

angular code

```
var app = angular.module('formExample', []);

app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.master = {};
  $scope.nrofrows = 0;

  $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);



      $scope.another = angular.copy()
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
  };

  $scope.reset();
}]);
 app.controller('addRow', function ($scope) {

        $scope.getValues = function () {




            var allInputs = $(':input');

            @* przy selected ewentualnie jeszcze zamiania :select na klase/id*@
            var selected = $(".optns option:selected").each(function ($scope) {
                $scope.arraySels.push($(this));
            });
                var quantities = $('.formElement :input').attr['number'].each(function () {
                    $scope.arrayQuants.push($(this));
                });

                var texts = $('.formElement :input').attr['text'].each(function () {
                    $scope.arrayTexts.push($(this));
                });

                alert("works" + $scope.arrayQuants);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with angular, but if you are using jQuery you can simply use the `serializeArray()` method to get your form data.

> [**.serializeArray()**](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)
>
> **Description:** *Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.*

Just make sure to add `name` attributes to your `input` elements.

Since your `form` elements are dynamically create you could add a submit event handler to them by delegating the event.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.simple-form', function(e) {...
```

Whenever the `submit` event is triggert you can pass the event target to your `getValues`  function to serialize the form data.

Here is a pure jQuery example, hope it helps.

```js
$(document).on('submit', '.simple-form', function(e) {
  getValues(this);
  e.preventDefault();
})

var getValues = function (currForm) {
  var formData = $(currForm).serializeArray();
  console.log(formData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="formExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-controller="addRow" ng-click="addLine()">Dodaj przycisk</button>

  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <div class="here">
      <div class="formElement">
        Klasa:<select name="select" class="optns" ng-model="user.class">
        <option selected value="1"> Rodzaj... </option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        @*tutaj beda dodane opcje*@
        </select>
        Ilość: <input name="num" type="number" ng-model="user.number" value=""/><br />
        Uwagi: <input name="user" type="text" ng-model="user.text" value=""/><br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey David! Thx for help - I implemented it and it works meaning that it does the event and function you gave, but the object array is empty (meaning it doesn't take any values from the form)

Comment: EDIT It takes value only of the first element in the form and ignores the ones added dynamiclly

Comment: Did you add name attributes to all your input elements and the select element ?

Comment: Yep. At first I missed it (no values) but then it worked only for the first (edit) element in the form.

Comment: btw David do you think this might be beacuse the document in the js isn't the document after appending html? meaning that it isn't refreshed or sth?

Comment: lol I'm retarded mate :) I forgot to change the html injected into the site by clicking the buton. thank you very much! I spent last 3 days on this task now I'm a little bit further !

Comment: Nice to hear that it is working now. ;) Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div ng-app="formExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <div class="here">
        <div class="formElement">
            Klasa:<select class="optns" ng-model="user.class">
                <option selected value="1"> Rodzaj... </option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                @*tutaj beda dodane opcje*@
            </select>
            Ilość: <input type="number" ng-model="user.number" value=""/><br />
            Uwagi: <input type="text" ng-model="user.text" value=""/><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit"  ng-click="update()" value="Copy" />
</form>
<pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
<pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

var app = angular.module('formExample', []);

app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.master = {};
$scope.user = {};
$scope.nrofrows = 0;

$scope.update = function(user) {
$scope.master = {};
angular.copy($scope.user, $scope.master);
};
}]);
```

Check with this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tojopaul/oxxakc1n/) .I think this will help you

Comment: thx for help Paul, though it's of no use without appending new html (the buton on the top of the code)

Comment: @Tojo - this seams to be the right solution. Thx for your help. +1